# Create new DF with selected columns and conditional selection

Tags: python, dataframe, conditional-statements

I have a DF with 15 columns, out of which there's only 5 useful columns I will be referring to. Additionally, I want only rows that will satisfy a condition. These are my codes, used in jupyter notebook.

```
cancelled = df[df['CANCELLED'] == 1]

cols_of_interest = ['DAY_OF_WEEK','AIRLINE','ORIGIN_AIRPORT','CANCELLED','DEPARTURE_DELAY']

new_df = cancelled[cols_of_interest]
```

Now i have my `new_df` with the selected columns and that satisfy the condition where 'cancelled' = 1. But is there a more pythonic way of doing this?

Appreciate any inputs I can get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for that:

```
cols_of_interest = ['DAY_OF_WEEK','AIRLINE','ORIGIN_AIRPORT','CANCELLED','DEPARTURE_DELAY']

new_df = df.loc[df['CANCELLED'] == 1, cols_of_interest]
```

More detailed information in [the doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-label).